# Not able to run hybrid application in windows phone 8 in IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-runtime

I made a project in IBM Worklight Version 6.2.I am have added android,iOS and WindowPhone8 Enviournment for the project.I am able to build and run the application in android and iOS.But when i imported the project in VS2012 for windowPhone8 It is not Working.It is not showing the Css and the click events are not working.Seems like it did not loaded Js and css but these files are present in folder structure.

Do i need to do any changes or am i doing anything wrong.Kindly help me running my project in Windows phone 8.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Exactly what did you import? Did you have the complete "native" folder available before trying to build it? You can also try a "build environment" within the Worklight Studio , before opening the project in Visual Studio

Comment: I Tried that too but still it is not working...:(

Comment: Upload your project. Let's see what the problem might be

Comment: how can i share my project..???

Comment: Dropbox, Google drive...PMR

Comment: Hi Idan and Vivin If i am Inspecting the issue in Internet Explorer 11 .It is giving me an issue of at this Line....                 var configurationString = localStorage.getItem(KEY_REMOTE_STORAGE_CONFIG);
..Can you help me resolving this issue..

Comment: How do you expect us to help when you do not provide the project? I do not see any issues running a Worklight 6.2 ,WindowsPhone8 environment. It is very possible something isn't right in your project or your environment. Do you get the same error when executing a plain and simple project as well? Or is it specific to your application?

Answer (score 0):

From tests performed, the Windows environment is built and displayed correctly. You've been asked to provide the project where this is happening to you. Do that.

Try cleaning Visual Studio's cache, try to preview your app in MobileFirst Studio and make sure there are no errors.